# Cassandra find records where list is empty

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-driver

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE shipment (
    shipment_id TIMEUUID,
    dropoff_contact person,
    job_ids list<TIMEUUID>,
    deleted boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY(shipment_id)
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS job_ids ON loadex.shipment (job_ids);
```

Is there any way to query this table for empty job_ids:

I have tried these, they are not working:

> SELECT * FROM shipment where job_ids=[]

> SELECT * FROM shipment where job_ids=null

Comment: No, there is not any way to query by an empty/null collection.

Comment: @Aaron Then how can I do this? what is the work around what do you suggest?

Comment: workaround: I have added another boolean column called `assigned`  and created an index on that. I am handling if list is empty set assigned to false on the application level.

Comment: It’s a by-product of Cassandra’s storage design.  Finding a value of null/empty requires an exhaustive scan of all data.  It’s something that’s easier for a RDBMS to handle.  Also, creating a secondary index on a low cardinality column (ex: Boolean) is not going to perform well at all.

Comment: should I add a primary composite primary key then?

Comment: also should i use materialized views in a production app? cassandra documentation say MVs are experimental in the latest 4.0 release.